Hide long-press menu on Google Chrome (Android) when element is obscured
Consider the following rudimentary example:
<html style="height: 100%">
    <body style="height: 100%">
    <div id="overlay" style="display:none; width:100%; height:100%; position: absolute; background-color:white">
        Hello there
    </div>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block'">
        Show menu
    </button>
    <h1>Some text</h1>
    </body>
</html>

You can see it live here. When viewing this page in Google Chrome on an Android, if you long-tap "Some text" you get the long press menu with contextual options, as shown bellow:

If while the contextual menu is still active the element you're highlighting gets hidden, for example because another element gets in front of it, the menu is still visible, which looks wonky:

How can I prevent that?
Notes:

The same doesn't happen on Firefox
Somehow Google.com manages this well. Say for example you highlight some text on the search results and then you click on your profile icon to open the settings menu. The contextual menu gets hidden then, even on Chrome. Haven't figured out why.

